# Image to resize from small to big - without adjusting the image size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-resizing

I’m trying to do this without adjusting the size of the image because when I did adjust the size of the image, it displayed wider - making it look like a fat can than a thin can. Also, it was repeating the image again as there was more space.

Here is my work: - https://codepen.io/Rosstopherrr/pen/LoKmJa 3

But what I’ve been trying to do is have a mouseover function. The size of the can needs to be small but when the cursor hovers the product it will display large, so the viewer can see the product clearly. Basically, there is 6 different favoured drinking bottle and cans. The client wants me to have the user have the option to look at the drinking product by using the mouse cursor, so in other words, the product will enlarge to see it clearly, whilst it is spinning in 3d.

Am I in the right track here? I’ve tried changing the height size of my div classes and, as expected, did not work. Any solutions here without changing the size of the image??

Any ideas???

Image Dimensions -
Width: 15.61 CM
Height: 11.6 CM
Resolution 150 pixels/inches
Resulting size - 248KB

REST OF MY CODE RESULT IS IN THE CODEPEN LINK - https://codepen.io/Rosstopherrr/pen/LoKmJa 3

JAVASCRIPT CODE BELOW is not a finish code but an idea of what I am trying to do with the JS function.

```
<script>
    var chnageSize = document.getElementsByClassName('side');
    chnageSize.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        chnageSize.style.height = "5000px"
        chnageSize.style.width = "5000px"
    })
    chnageSize();
</script>
```

Comment: Probably just add `scale(2)` on the bottle div when it is hovered ?

Comment: By "the image", do you mean an ``<img>``?  If so, and if the suggested ``scale(2)`` doesn't work or you really want to do it in JS, try changing only the height or width, and leave the other dimension set to "auto".  That will preserve its aspect ratio.  (You might also want to check the spelling of "chnage" (multiple times) in your code.

Comment: BINGO!!! thank you. this is what I've been looking for!! thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without the use of javascript try adding something like this to your CSS:

```
.bottle:hover {
  transform: rotateX(0deg)
    rotateY(0deg)
    rotateZ(0deg)
    translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px)
    scale(1.5);
}
```

Note the `scale(1.5);` at the end of the transform. You can change 1.5 to anything you want to change the size of the larger image. 1.5 means that it will be 1.5 times the size.

If you want it to animate to and from the larger appearance then change your .bottle CSS to something like this:

```
.bottle {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 10.125px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg)
    rotateY(0deg)
    rotateZ(0deg)
    translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg)
    rotateY(0deg)
    rotateZ(0deg)
    translate3d(650px, 190px, 40px);
  transform: rotateX(0deg)
    rotateY(0deg)
    rotateZ(0deg)
    translate3d(350px, 190px, 40px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Note the `transition: all 0.2s;` at the beginning. The animation will take 0.2 seconds to complete.